# Variável perdendo valor em php

Tags: php

Estou com o seguinte problema. Tenho uma lista de registros com nome, idade e telefone por exemplo. Em cada registro eu tenho um botão para visualizar todas as informações desse cadastro.

Quando clico nesse botão ele leva o usuário para um próxima tela que vamos chamar de "Visualizar Dados". Quando eu levo o usuário para essa tela eu mando o ID desse cadastro para eu realizar a busca dos demais dados.

Na página "Visualizar Dados" eu tenho seguinte código:

```
<?php  

//Identifica se houve post para a página atual
if (isset($_POST["btnVisualizarPaciente"]) == "btnVisualizarPaciente") {

    //Faz requisição do arquivo de classe que realiza a busca dos dados
    require_once("class/class_load.php");
    $classeLoad = new VisualizarDados();
    $request = $classeLoad->requestDados();

}

?>

//HTML para apresentar os dados da busca
<div>Nome: <?php echo $nome; ?></div>
<div>Idade: <?php echo $idade; ?></div>
<div>Telefone: <?php echo $telefone; ?></div>
<div>Endereço: <?php echo $endereco; ?></div>
```

No arquivo classe do php eu tenho o seguinte código

```
    class VisualizarDados {

    public function requestDados() {

        $idBusca = $_POST['idBusca'];

        require_once("inc/database.php");
        //SQL Carrega os dados pessoais do paciente
        $selectDados = $pdo->prepare(" SELECT * FROM tb_cadastros_sistema WHERE id = :idBusca");
        $selectDados->bindParam(':idBusca', $idBusca);
        $selectDados->execute();

        if ($resultDados = $selectDados->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            $nome = $resultDados['nome'];
            $idade = $resultDados['idade'];
            $telefone = $resultDados['telefone'];
            $endereco = $resultDados['endereco'];

        }else{
            print "Erro ao carregar os dados, por favor contate o suporte";
        }

    }
}
```

O código que utilizo para buscar os dados funciona perfeitamente, porém ele não exibe os valores da busca na página "Visualizar Dados". Fica apresentando erro de variável indefinida.

Comment: Deve ser problema de escopo pela mensagem de erro. `$nome` etc existem apenas no método `requestDados()` as variavieis de mesmo nome em `Visualizar Dados.php` não são as mesmas.

Comment: E como eu poderia estar resolvendo?

Comment: $nome = $request ->nome; seta ela no arquivo principal

Comment: Seu método deveria retornar um array com as informações. Se for só um registro pode fazer `return  $selectDados->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você não está retornando e nem armazenando os dados em uma variável que poderá ser acessada posteriormente.

Você pode alterar sua classe "VisualizarDados" para:

```
<?php

class VisualizarDados {

    private $nome;
    private $idade;
    private $telefone;
    private $endereco;

    public function requestDados() {

        $idBusca = $_POST['idBusca'];

        require_once("inc/database.php");
        //SQL Carrega os dados pessoais do paciente
        $selectDados = $pdo->prepare(" SELECT * FROM tb_cadastros_sistema WHERE id = :idBusca");
        $selectDados->bindParam(':idBusca', $idBusca);
        $selectDados->execute();

        if ($resultDados = $selectDados->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            /* Armazena os valores nas propriedades globais (da classe) */
            $ths->nome = $resultDados['nome'];
            $ths->idade = $resultDados['idade'];
            $ths->telefone = $resultDados['telefone'];
            $ths->endereco = $resultDados['endereco'];

        }else{
            print "Erro ao carregar os dados, por favor contate o suporte";
        }
    }

    /* Retorna os valores armazenados */
    public function getName() {
        return $this->nome;
    }

    public function getOldYear() {
        return $this->idade;
    }

    public function getPhone() {
        return $this->telefone;
    }

    public function getAddress() {
        return $this->endereco;
    }
}
```

Dessa forma você poderá capturar os valores acessando `$variavel->getProperty()`. Ex:

```
<?php  

    //Identifica se houve post para a página atual
    if (isset($_POST["btnVisualizarPaciente"]) == "btnVisualizarPaciente") {

        //Faz requisição do arquivo de classe que realiza a busca dos dados
        require_once("class/class_load.php");
        $classeLoad = new VisualizarDados();
        $classeLoad->requestDados();
    ?>

    //HTML para apresentar os dados da busca
    <div>Nome: <?php echo $classeLoad->getName(); ?></div>
    <div>Idade: <?php echo $classeLoad->getOldYear(); ?></div>
    <div>Telefone: <?php echo $classeLoad->getPhone(); ?></div>
    <div>Endereço: <?php echo $classeLoad->getAddress(); ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Testando essa alternativa, ele está me apresentando o seguinte erro: Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object

Comment: @JoãoVictor Corrigir minha resposta.

Comment: Agora deu certo amigo, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

```
            class VisualizarDados {

        public function requestDados() {
            $idBusca = $_POST['idBusca'];
            require_once("inc/database.php");
            //SQL Carrega os dados pessoais do paciente
            $selectDados = $pdo->prepare(" SELECT * FROM tb_cadastros_sistema WHERE id = :idBusca");
            $selectDados->bindParam(':idBusca', $idBusca);
            $selectDados->execute();

            if ($resultDados = $selectDados->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $dados = $resultDados;
            }else{
                $dados =  "Erro ao carregar os dados, por favor contate o suporte";
            }
 return $dados;
        }

    }
```